# 0xc0000142 Error when calling CreateProcess while spoofing parent pid

Tags: c, windows

I am currently trying to launch a program while spoofing the parent pid. Below is my code that does all the work..

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    STARTUPINFOEX si = { sizeof(si) };
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    SIZE_T attributeSize;

    InitializeProcThreadAttributeList(NULL, 1, 0, &attributeSize);
    si.lpAttributeList = (LPPROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, attributeSize);
    InitializeProcThreadAttributeList(si.lpAttributeList, 1, 0, &attributeSize);

    DWORD dwParentPID = 14256; //cmd.exe pid

    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, dwParentPID);
    if (!hProcess) {
        return -1;
    }

    UpdateProcThreadAttribute(si.lpAttributeList, 0, PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PARENT_PROCESS, &hProcess, sizeof(HANDLE), NULL, NULL);

    LPCWSTR spawnProcess1 = L"C:\\Users\\user\\source\\repos\\random_testing\\x64\\Debug\\test.exe";
    CreateProcess(spawnProcess1, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT, NULL, NULL, (STARTUPINFO*)&si, &pi);
    return 0;
}
```

The second program I have is just a program that prints hello world.

test.exe

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    getchar();
    return 1;
}
```

When I run the above code to spoof the PPID of test.exe I get an error "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000142). Click OK to close the application." I am trying to spoof the cmd.exe process.

If I try do CreateProcess on something like notepad or calc, it will work. But some reason it does not for my simple hello world.

Comment: This has something to do with this being a console mode app.  Inheriting the console from the parent process is a big deal, clearly that can be a problem when the new parent is a console mode app as well and did not actively participate.  The posted code works fine when I used CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE | EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT for the 6th CreateProcess() argument.